# Entity framework with Uint DataContractJsonSerializer

Tags: c#, json, entity-framework, uint, datacontractjsonserializer

I have an api which I call that return JSON.
This I deserialize to objects using DataContractJsonSerializer.

My JSON can have uint values ranging higher than int.MaxValue so I need to have a uint property on my classes to avoid exception.

This class I use for an entitymodel with codefirst ( Entity framework ).

The problem here is that EF6 does not support uint so I don't even get columns in my table when I update the database.

Now the question is, how can I solve this the most simple way if I want to convert the JSON directly to my model entitys. Something I can do with the serializer to put uint values into int ( I dont really care if it gets negative as long as it works ) or maybe I can somehow got EF to accept my uints..

I can ofcourse use two entities and convert between but Id like to avoid this if possible?`

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a long / int64. This is a 64 bit integer an fully supported by EF.